# Querying data in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I am developing windows application in c#.

I have a gridview with about 40k records in it.

In that gridview i have checkbox.

I wanted to update only those records which are checked.

I have written following code for it>>

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvTradeFile.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                try
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = gvTradeFile.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                    bool check = (bool)cell.Value;

                    if (check)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cmd = new SqlCommand("update tradeFile set Party_Code='" + txtTransferPartyCode.Text + "' where Party_Code='" + gvTradeFile.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "' and TradeNo='" + gvTradeFile.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date='" + gvTradeFile.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value.ToString() + "' and OrderNo='" + gvTradeFile.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
```

In this if we look at the `for loop` i am dealing with each row in the grid.

Is there any specific technique through which i can directly take only Checked rows[via checkbox in grid] in for loop?

Above code works fine but because of each and every row is checked, exe is getting hanged.

Please help me.

Comment: May be a silly question, but you're display 40k rows on screen? Is someone manually checking these?

Comment: Yeah manually check is done on rows. Also filters are provided.@DaveRook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on the checkbox chek event you should maintain a datatable or a dictionary if checkbox is checked and then bulk update the database. You can google for bulk update

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure, but I think you can not get any gridview function that returns the checked rows.

However, you *can* do this manually by keeping the record the which row of the gridview checkbox is checked. Than update your database according to your list you maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options.

1. You could stick the save onto a new thread, then either have your colleague/client assume it's saved or display a 'saving' graphic.
2. Split the entire thing up to 1000 records at once. This way, you're only showing first 1k, edit, save. Then show next 1k, edit, save! This will reduce the overhead.